# How to tell if variable exists

Tags: pandoc

I want to run this when `@pubreaderonename` is defined.

in the `.cls` file:

```
\def\pubreaderone#1#2#3{\gdef\@pubreaderonename{#1}\gdef\@pubreaderonetitle{#2}\gdef\@pubreaderoneaffiliation{#3}}


\if@pubreaderonename
\par
\signature{Thesis Reader}{\@pubreaderonename \\ \@pubreaderonetitle \\ \@pubreaderoneaffiliation}
\fi
```

in the latex file:

```
$if(
    pubreaders-1-name)$
    \pubreaderone{$pubreaders-1-name$}{$pubreaders-1-title$}{$pubreaders-1-affiliation$}
    $endif$
```

I am getting this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\readerpage ...affiliation } \if@pubreaderonename
                                                  \par \signature {Thesis Re...

l.106 \begin{readerpage}

pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

So I need the code to only execute when`@pubreaderonename` is set.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says that `\if@pubreaderonename` is undefined. If you want to test, whether `\@pubreaderisonename` is defined, then this can be done by:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname @pubreaderisonename\endcsname\relax
  % \@pubreaderisonename is undefined or \relax
\else
  % \@pubreaderisonename is set
\fi
```

Also, this should evaluated *after* the place, where `\pubreaderone` might be called.

Comment: That reminds me: I encourage package developers to place flags in their code, true/false depending on whether a variable has been set. That is: Create a new if. Set the if as true, when the defining command is used. Then, instead of the hard-to-read code with expandafter, the user could test the if.